# Boarding & Internal Transfer facility conneting flight with 2 PNRin domestic flight

Tags: spicejet

I was booking a ticket from Madurai to Chennai (7.45 A.M to 9 A.M) and Chennai to Kolkata (9.55 A.M to 12.20 P.M) on October 11, 2015 with two [PNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_name_record)s but both are on same flight (Spicejet) and both are connecting flights. i was continue request to spicejet to please provide me boarding directly Madurai to Kolkata & Internal Transfer from Chennai airport, i have no knowledge about time duration by mistake ticket booked then please suggest can i take any legal step against him or not.

Comment: Can you clear up some things: (1) do you want to fly from Madurai to Kolkata without leaving the airport in Chennai? (2) since there are 12 hours in between the two flights, what do you mean by "boarding directly Madurai to Kolkara"? You have 12 hours in Chennai! This should be more than enough transfer time even if your two flights are booked on different PNRs. So where exactly is the problem?

Comment: 1) firstly clear timing 9.55 A.M form chennai by mistake 9.55 P.M written, Actually i want to fly Madurai to Kolkata and i had ticket madurai to chennai & chennai to kolkata both tickets are spicejet, after booked ticket then i know  both flight are conneting.

Comment: Ok, so what did the Spicejet guys reply when you asked them to "provide me boarding directly Madurai to Kolkata & Internal Transfer from Chennai airport".

Comment: they are reply me given below                                                                 We would like to inform you that their should be minimum gap of 2 hours between the two flights.
 
Further please note that Airline is not liable for any manual made connections by the passenger if any of the flight is disrupted.
 
Furthermore, we would like to inform you that check –in counters closes strictly 45 minutes prior to the flight departure time.
 
In case you need further clarification/assistance, please feel free to get in touch with us.

Comment: please reply sir

Comment: The minimum connect time at Chennai for international-to-domestic is two hours. I think your itinerary is impossible.

Comment: but both flight connected and both domestic

Comment: Mahesh, do you have any checked baggage and does your airline allow web checking ~24 hours prior to departure with self-printed boarding passes? I don't know about how Indian airports work, but in Europe, you may be able to make your connection by staying airside after landing in your transit airport.

Answer (score 2):

**You will likely miss your connecting flight.**  If an agent booked this for you, it's not a valid itinerary and they should change it at their own cost.  If you booked this on your own, you're out of luck, all you can do is ask Spicejet to rebook you on a different flight and (if you're lucky) give you credit for the earlier flight.

[Spicejet connecting flights FAQ](http://www.spicejet.com/ConnectingFlightsFaq.aspx):

> Any Booking with respect to the Connecting Flights shall be required
>   to be booked in advance and both segments in the Connecting Flights
>   shall be confirmed **on the same PNR**, fees & surcharges will be
>   applicable only with respect to one segment.

Since your flights have two different PNRs, they're not considered a connecting flight.

> At the time of check-in passenger(s) will be issued boarding card(s) only up to the point of transit. ... for domestic flights the check in starts 02 hours prior to the departure time and **closes 45 minutes prior to the departure time**.

Even if you have a connecting flight, you will be required to check-in again at your connection point.